# Can daily viewcounts be added to the data dump?

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

An interesting addition to the data dump would be the daily/hourly/whatever view counts for the websites. This could be used to see what happened to SO when proposal X came out, what time of day is the most active (if it was hourly), what day of the week is the most active, activity to question ratio, and many other things.

Before you say "What about `Users.Views` and `Posts.ViewCount`?", they aren't usable since they only list the *total*, not the breakdown of when it happened. The only statistics you could draw are monthly, which is useless.

If your worried about size, then your exaggerating what I'm asking. Daily is tiny, only 7 rows for an entire week. Hourly is a bit bigger, 168 rows per week. Considering other tables are millions of rows long, this won't affect size at all considering the growth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only store ViewCounts as a single field integer counter, so what you're proposing is not possible.

Comment: Well then how does the SE Site page (http://stackexchange.com/sites) say 498k views/day if its stored in a single field? And the value for programmers changes from 5k to 6k and back down occasionally

Comment: @TheLQ: I'm assuming it's pulled from elsewhere (probably a web server statistic or something like that).

Comment: @TheLQ - iirc those are backed by the API, and are contractually *average* daily view counts if that's the case.