# Make Number of Visits default analytics graph?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-abilities, analytics

The default graph on moderator analytics for views is the "Total Page Views" graph.  I think it would be better to display the "Number of Visits" graph by default, as this is the same metric used to evaluate [traffic on StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

It's also a more meaningful metric of how active the site is.

Answer (score -2):

[According to Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64658/can-daily-viewcounts-be-added-to-the-data-dump), viewcounts are stored as a single entry thats incremented instead of a big table logging everything. So for right now, thats not possible

Comment: These are graphs that mods have available to them already.  @CRoss is just asking for the default selection in a dropdown list to be changed.

Comment: @rchern Hmm... so now I'm confused about the question thats linked. If its stored as a single field as Jeff said, then how can mods draw graphs? Or is Jeff wrong?